Flops connect minimal models of algebraic spaces?
According to a Kawamata's result, two projective minimal models of the same variety are connected through a sequence of flops. In particular, a birational map $f\colon X\to X'$ between Calabi-Yau manifolds can be decomposed in a sequence of flops.
Will this result still be true if we drop the projectivity assumption and instead assume that $X$ is projective but $X'$ is only an algebraic space (= Moishezon manifold if we work over $\mathbb C$)? Moishezon manifolds are by definition complex manifolds that are birational to projective manifolds. If $X'$ is a Moishezon manifold with trivial canonical class, then we can find a birational morphism $Y\to X'$ with $Y$ projective. By running MMP we can find a projective minimal model $X$ of $Y$ and I'd like to prove that this birational morphism is a sequence of flops.

What is your definition of “flop” in the setting of non-projective proper algebraic spaces?

@JasonStarr The usual definition never mentions projectivity. A $D$-flop is a triangle of small maps $f\colon X\rightarrow Y\leftarrow X'\colon f'$ such that $D$ is $f$-anti-ample and the strict transform $D'$ in $X'$ is $f'$-ample. A flop is a $D$-flop for some divisor $D$

I thought I had produced a counterexample, but now I am not so sure.
